# Dynamically adjust DIV width JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, html, width, scrollbar

I know this can have a simple solution but I can't find the way.

I'm building an horizontal "scroll box" using this JQuery plugin (TinyScrollbar): http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/

I have two "scroll box" on every pages, but with different "child" boxes inside (in one row).

This is HTML code for the first "widget".

```
<div id="scrollbar1">
    <div class="scrollbar">
        <div class="track"><div class="thumb"><div class="end"></div></div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="viewport">
        <div class="overview">
        <div class="item">Content</div>
        <div class="item">Content</div>
        <div class="item">Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is HTML code for second "widget".

```
<div id="scrollbar1">
    <div class="scrollbar">
        <div class="track"><div class="thumb"><div class="end"></div></div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="viewport">
        <div class="overview">
            <div class="item">Content</div>
                <div class="item">Content</div>
                <div class="item">Content</div>
                <div class="item">Content</div>
                <div class="item">Content</div>
                <div class="item">Content</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Every "item" has a fixed height and width (ie 100px) and float left (for one row show).
All items are containeb by div with class "overview". 
The CSS for "overview"

```
#scrollbar1 .overview {
    left: 0;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 300px;
}
```

My problem is: how to dynamically change the width of the div when "items" are > of three or < of three to display all items in a row?
I know that I can use the update function of the plugin, but I don't know how to implement it.

I'm using this JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar({ axis: 'x'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML code is a bit incorrect, change it to:

```
<div id="scrollbar1">
    <div class="scrollbar"><div class="track"><div class="thumb"><div class="end"></div></div></div></div>
    <div class="viewport">
        <div class="overview">
                    <div class="item">Content</div>
                    <div class="item">Content</div>
                    <div class="item">Content</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
<div id="scrollbar1">
    <div class="scrollbar"><div class="track"><div class="thumb"><div class="end"></div></div></div></div>
    <div class="viewport">
        <div class="overview">
            <div class="item">Content</div>
            <div class="item">Content</div>
            <div class="item">Content</div>
            <div class="item">Content</div>
            <div class="item">Content</div>
            <div class="item">Content</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I missed a </div>. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

2 scrollbars on 1 page? Then why both widgets have same id ?